# Blank page when accessing page in admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting a blank page when I click on the page link in the administration in WordPress

> /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page

It only happens with pages, all the other post types are fine. I have lots of pages, nearly 2000.

Here is what i tried so far without luck:

- switching to default theme
- deactivating all plugins
- deactivating revisions in wp-config

Here is some of my php settings:

- WP Memory Limit: 256MB
- PHP Post Max Size: 8MB
- PHP Time Limit: 300
- PHP Max Input Vars: 1920

When I turn on WP_debug I get this when I click on pages:

```
Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget is deprecated since  version 4.3.0! Use

__construct()

in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3457

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 80 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2258
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about your **theme folder structure**??..you have something called `page.php`.?

Comment: Yes, I have page.php in my theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Memory issue. Can you please add following in your wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT' , '512M' );
```

Let's know if tihs fixes your memory issue? As currently error is saying 256M memory assigned is not enough for the page to load.

Comment: I did that, but I also found that I needed to to edit the following: `./wp-includes/default-constants.php:28: define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );`